# How do I run a virtual machine using the host IP address?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I want my VM to be assigned the IP address of the host.

My VM (Ubuntu OS 12.04 LTS) is installed inside my Windows 7 host machine. When I connect the host to the network, it is assigned an IP address by the DHCP. The network does not allow the physical machine to request for more than one IP address; it will lock the LAN connection immediately.

How can I configure the VM to get the network connectivity from the host using the same IP address?

Thank you.

Comment: VMWare and VirtualBox are different products. This question is not a duplicate, just similar. In any case, my answer suggests using port forwarding which isn't addressed in the VMWare reply.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two machines having the same IP address otherwise traffic would be impossible between them. There are however several ways for your VM to communicate to/from the Internet in your case.

For outgoing traffic, you can use the default network configuration which is NAT, i.e. VirtualBox will translate your internal IP address to the host one.

For incoming traffic, you can configure port forwarding for specific ports to be handled by your VM instead of the host.

Have a look to this blog page for details: https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/networking_in_virtualbox1